# Bijection on a subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}^V$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $k<n$. Let $G(V,E)$ be an arbitrary graph s.t. $|V|=n$. Now $X\subset \{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}^{V}$ (this is the set of functions from $V$ to $\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$) is defined as: $x \in X$ if and only if $x(v)\neq x(w)$ for all edges $(v,w)\in E$ (where $v,w\in V$).

Let me define a function $f$ on $X$ as: $f(x)=y$ where $y\in \{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}^V$ and $y(v)=x(v)+1\mod k$ for all $v\in V$.

> I am trying to determine if $f$ is a bijection on $X$?

My attempt: Firstly, $f(x)\in X$ because if $y=f(x)$, then $y(v)\neq y(w)$ for all edges $(v,w)\in E$. Secondly, if $x_1,x_2\in X$ with $x_1\neq x_2$, then $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ because if $f(x_1)=y_1,f(x_2)=y_2$, then $y_1(v)\neq y_2(v)$ for all $v\in V$. So $f$ is one-one and I am not sure how to prove that it is onto. Any ideas?

Comment: It should be $y\in \{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}^V$, not $y\in \{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}^n$

Comment: Something about the definition of $X$ is not very clear. If I understand correctly, for a connected graph every function of $X$ is a constant. If a graph has $s$ components, then the function of $X$ is a function constant on components and taking $s$ different values. The $1$ shift in this case is of course a bijection on $X$

Comment: @kabenyuk It seems like you're asking for $x(v) = x(w)$ for all edges $vw$, but the question wants $x(v) \ne x(w)$ for all edges $vw$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, you are indeed right. Everything I said in my comment should be attributed to the $\overline{G}$ graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof that $x \in X \implies f(x) \in X$ is fine.

I disagree with your proof that if $x_1 \ne x_2$, then $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$. First of all, you are just claiming that $y_1(v) \ne y_2(v)$ for all $v$. Second, this claim is false: we can show that $y_1 \ne y_2$, but there may still be some $v$ for which $y_1(v) \ne y_2(v)$. Instead, we can argue as follows:

- Since $x_1 \ne x_2$, there must be **some** $v$ such that $x_1(v) \ne x_2(v)$.
- Then if we let $f(x_1) = y_1$ and $f(x_2) = y_2$ as you did, we can show that for the same vertex $v$, $y_1(v) \ne y_2(v)$.

But the easiest way to prove that $f$ is a bijection is to prove that it has an inverse, and the natural inverse to consider is the function $g$ such that for all $x \colon V \to \{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$, we have $g(x)(v) = x(v) - 1 \bmod k$.

Once you check that this is an inverse, this implies that $f$ and $g$ are bijections on the set of all functions.

Then, once you check that $x \in X \implies g(x) \in X$ (this is the same as your first step), this implies that $f$ and $g$ are also bijections on $X$.

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking $\textbf{any}$ bijection $f:\mathbb{Z}_k\to \mathbb{Z}_k$ induces a bijection $g$ on $\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}^V$ where, if $x\in X$ and $v\in V$, $g(x)(v)=f(x(v))$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and the idea is essentially the same. To prove this, we want $g$ to have an inverse, and to construct an inverse for $g$, use the inverse of $f$.